# Overloading of hidden friends by differences only in (mutually exclusive) requires-clauses: legal or an ODR-violation?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, friend-function

Consider the following class template, which contains two (hidden) friend declarations *of the same friend* (same *function type*; see below), which also defines the friend (and the friend is thus inline), but with the definition conditional on (mutually exclusive) *requires-clauses*:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {};

template<int N>
struct S : public Base {
    friend int foo(Base&) requires (N == 1) { return 1; }
    friend int foo(Base&) requires (N == 2) { return 3; }
};
```

[[dcl.fct]/8](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#8) states that trailing *requires-clauses* are *not* part of a function's type [**emphasis** mine]:

> The return type, the parameter-type-list, the ref-qualifier, the cv-qualifier-seq, and the exception specification, **but not the default arguments** ([dcl.fct.default]) **or the trailing requires-clause** ([dcl.decl]), **are part of the function type**.

which means that the two definitions above is an ODR-violation for a case where both definitions are instantiated; if we only focus on a single translation unit, [[basic.def.odr]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#1) would be violated:

> **No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any** variable, **function**, class type, enumeration type, template, default argument for a parameter (for a function in a given scope), or default template argument.

and in a single TU this violation should arguably be diagnosable (no "need" for "ill-formed, NDR"). I'm trying understand the rules for *when* the definitions above will be instantiated; or if this is entirely implementation-defined (or even ill-formed before reaching instantiation phase).

Both Clang and GCC<sup>(1)</sup> accepts the following program

```
// ... as above

// (A)
int main() {
    S<1> s1{};
    std::cout << foo(s1);  // Clang & GCC: 1
}
```

For programs (B) through (D) below, however, Clang accepts them all whereas GCC rejects them all with a re-definition error:

```
// (B)
int main() {
    S<1> s1{};
    S<2> s2{};  // GCC: re-definition error of 'foo'
}

// (C)
int main() {
    S<1> s1{};
    S<2> s2{};  // GCC: re-definition error of 'foo'
    std::cout << foo(s1);  // Clang: 1
}

// (D)
template struct S<1>;
template struct S<2>;  // GCC: re-definition error of 'foo'

int main() {}
```

It's only when actually trying to invoke the friend function via ADL on *both* specializations that Clang actually emits an error

```
// (E)
int main() {
    S<1> s1{};
    S<2> s2{};  // GCC: re-definition error of 'foo'
    std::cout << foo(s1); // MSVC: ambiguous call
    std::cout << foo(s2);  
    // Clang error: definition with same mangled name
    //              '_Z3fooR4Base' as another definition
}
```

and we may note that only MSVC actually reaches a state of seemingly accepting both definitions after which it fails as expect ("ambiguous call").

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/9noPWW).

#### Question

- Can hidden non-template friend functions of class templates (friend declarations where the friends are also defined in the class) be overloaded only by a difference in (mutually exclusive) requires-clauses?

And, thus, which compiler is right here?

1. All (ill-formed NDR and/or implementation defined w.r.t. point of instantiation rules),
2. GCC
3. Clang
4. MSVC
5. None (example (E) is well-formed)

I have not been able to understand what rules that governs *when* a friend function declaration (of a class template) that is also a definition, is instantiated, particularly when *requires-clauses* are involved; possibly this is irrelevant, though, if the behaviour of GCC and Clang above are both incorrect.

---

<sub>(1) GCC HEAD 11.0.0,  Clang HEAD 12.0.0.</sub>

Comment: *"ODR-violation for a case where both definitions are instantiated;"*  instantiation has nothing to do with ODR. there are both definitions even if not instantiated.

Comment: @Jarod42 But then surely GCC and Clang should be able to diagnose such a same-TU ODR-violating definition? Wheres none of them does (unless we start to instantiate the related specializations). E.g. the hidden friend injection trick used for e.g. the circumventing private access rules hack relies on the fact the single and first instantiation of a given specialization is actually (explicitly) instantiated. On the other hand, the latter case make use of a (non-type) template parameter as part of it's definition, so it's quite clear why the definition needs to be deferred until instantiation.

Comment: ... However, arguably requires-clauses dependent on template params should fall under the same umbrella; albeit not something we _should_ be doing, which definition of the friend that is actually emitted seems eerily similar to the injection-into-hidden-friend trick, which is well-known to be conformant (albeit intended to, somehow, be banned as per CWG issue 2118), as long as we don't instantiate two specializations that would (like the friend injection trick) lead to an ODR-violation. But I'm speculating here, and would be grateful to be pointed to the relevant passages of the standard.

Comment: From [over#dcl-1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over#dcl-1), I understand there is 2 different `foo` (so no ODR violations). I think there is issue with both compiler to not have adjusted name mangling for this corner case.

Comment: So same rule as for regular methods (if you remove `friend`) normally.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah, thanks, [over.dcl]/1, albeit non-normative, should imply that both GCC and Clang are incorrect in failing example (E) above (and GCC for the rest). For a normative reference, [\[temp.friend\]/9](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.friend#9) may be what we're looking for (_"Such a constrained friend function [...] does not declare the same function [...] as a declaration in any other scope."_), and [\[temp.decls.general\]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.decls.general#2) is quite clear on the _"are separate definitions"_ for the case of constrained member functions of class templates.

Comment: @Jarod42 Would you like to compose an answer?

Comment: I also found that, but they are in the same scope here.

Comment: @Jarod42 The first statement in over#dcl-1 that you linked seems to cover it. There's even an example there that says those declarations are different (because of different requires-clauses).

Comment: @Jarod42 I find the scope of friend declarations kind of vague; if they are definitions they are in the _lexical_ scope of the class ([\[class.friend\]/7](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.friend#7)),but as per [\[class.friend\]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.friend#6) the friend function has namespace scope. What would _"any other scope"_ refer to from [temp.friend]/9? If only mentions friend declarations and not definitions (so the scope, in lack of a definition, is that of the enclosing namespace, and lexical scope doesn't apply as there is no definition to use it).

Comment: @cigien The only possible problem with [over.dcl]/1 is that it's non-normative (at least the interesting example; but maybe the normative text regarding the identity of declarations based on requires-clauses suffices). Either way, it very much gives us the standard's intention, but I'm still wondering whether [temp.friend]/9 is actually the normative text we're looking for or not. Arguably this kind of rule should not be covered under _"overloading"_ (we'd expect to find the _effects_ of the rule there, but not the root rule).

Comment: I think the normative text in over#dcl-1 is enough. And I don't see why the relevant text shouldn't be in overloading, unless making `f` a template makes any difference, and I don't think it should matter here.

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't think it's necessary to add the behavior of msvc, but if you're doing that, then you should add the results for all the snippets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [over#dcl-1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over#dcl-1),

> Two function declarations of the same name refer to the same function if they are in the same scope and have equivalent parameter declarations ([over.load]) and equivalent ([temp.over.link]) trailing requires-clauses, if any ([dcl.decl]).

> [Note 1: Since a constraint-expression is an unevaluated operand, equivalence compares the expressions without evaluating them.
> [Example 1:
> `template<int I> concept C = true;`
> `template<typename T> struct A {`
>   `void f() requires C<42>;      // #1`
>   `void f() requires true;       // OK, different functions`
> `};`
> — end example]
> — end note]

I understand there is 2 different `foo` (so no ODR violations) because of the differing requires clauses.

I think there is issue with all mentioned compilers to not cover this corner case.

Answer (score 1):

#### Different trailing requires-clauses distinguish declarations of hidden friends for different specializations from eachother

Clang and GCC are both wrong to reject the program. As pointed out in [@Jared42:s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64760824/4573247), [[over.dcl]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.dcl#1) should likewise apply for hidden friend declarations, such that the declarations in the OP:s example declare different friend functions.

Associated Clang bug report:

- [Bug 48872 - Rejects-valid for overloaded hidden non-template friend functions with mutually exclusive requires-clauses](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48872)

Associated GCC bug report:

- [Bug 98822 - Rejects-valid: instantiation of class template instantiates (all) constrained non-template friend definitions (, even those) with unsatisfied constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98822)

---

### Details

GCC is wrong by violation of 
[[temp.friend]/9](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.friend#9):

> A non-template friend declaration with a *requires-clause* shall be a definition.
> A friend function template with a constraint that depends on a template parameter from an enclosing template shall be a definition.
> Such a constrained friend function or function template declaration **does not declare the same function** or function template as a declaration **in any other scope.**

It was not clear to me at first that this separates friend declarations with specialization-exclusive requires-clauses, but as commented by the author of the paragraph (Hubert Tong; see details below), this is the intent of the paragraph:

> [...] the "does not declare" wording is meant to say that the friends declared by each specialization is unique.

Clang is wrong by violation of [[defns.signature.friend]](https://eel.is/c++draft/defns.signature.friend), which includes a trailing requires-clause (if any) in the signature of a non-template friend function [**emphasis** mine]:

> ⟨non-template friend function **with trailing *requires-clause***⟩ name, parameter-type-list, enclosing class, **and trailing *requires-clause***

meaning Clang should not generate the same mangled name for the two, separate (by separate requires-clauses) friend declarations.

MSVC is *likely* also wrong to the fail program (E) in the stage of overload resolution (with an ambiguity error), as e.g. `foo(s1)` should arguably only add candidates from `S<1>` to its candidate functions. Whether constraints checking can actually be applied for an argument that is `Base&` and not a particular specialization of `S` is another question, but the possible error should not be one of ambiguity but rather inability to fulfill the constraints of a candidate function.

**US115: Hidden non-template friends need a requires-clause**

US115 of [P2103R0](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2103r0.html) (*Core Language Changes for NB Comments at the February, 2020 (Prague) meeting*) proposed updating the standard rules for non-template hidden friends such that (also) non-template friend (functions) should be allowed to use trailing requires-clauses:

> #### US115. Hidden non-template friends need a requires-clause
>
> 1. Add the following after 3.20 [defns.signature]:
>
> > 3.21 [defns.signature.friend]
> >
> > **signature**
> >
> > **‹non-template friend function *with trailing requires-clause*› name, parameter-type-list (9.3.3.5 [dcl.fct]), enclosing class, and
> > *trailing requires-clause* (9.3 [dcl.decl])**
>
> 2. Add the following after 3.21 [defns.signature.templ]:
>
> > 3.23 [defns.signature.templ.friend]
> >
> > **signature**
> >
> > **‹friend function template with constraint involving enclosing template parameters› name, parameter-type-list (9.3.3.5 [dcl.fct]),
> > return type, enclosing class, *template-head*, and *trailing
> > requires-clause***
>
> 3. Change 13.7.4 [temp.friend] paragraph 9 as follows:
>
> > A non-template friend declaration <s>shall not have</s> **with** a requires-clause **shall be a definition. A friend function template
> > with a constraint that depends on a template parameter from an
> > enclosing template shall be a definition. Such a constrained friend
> > function or function template declaration does not declare the same
> > function or function template as a declaration in any other scope.**

the majority of the change affection an expansion of 
[[temp.friend]/9](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.friend#9).

US115 was recorded as [issue 114](https://github.com/cplusplus/nbballot/issues/114) in cplusplus/nbballot:

> #### US115 13.6.4 [temp.friend] Hidden non-template friends need a requires-clause
>
> Hidden friends that are non-templates currently cannot have a requires-clause, but this functionality is important and used throughout Ranges.
>
> Proposed change:
>
> Change [temp.friend]/9 to refer only to those friend declarations that are not any kind of templated entity.

and was implemented in [pull request #3782 to the standard draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/3782), particularly as per [the following commit](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/3782/commits/8e251fcfc59952686608513a4dcaa5455b7e7882):

> #### NB US 115 (C++20 CD): Hidden non-template friends need a requires-clause
>
> Added obviously-missing (if any) to the mention of a trailing
> requires-clause in the definition of signature for a friend function
> template.

I [asked for clarification](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/3782) (given the different implementations of the GCC, Clang, MSVC) regarding the expanded rule of [temp.friend]/9 w.r.t. overloading hidden non-template friends solely based differences in trailing requires-clauses, with the answer that this should (likely) be legal, and that both GCC and Clang are wrong to reject example (E) in their respective manners (it should be an overload resolution ambiguity error:

> **Hubert Tong (*hubert-reinterpretcast*)**
>
> I think MSVC is correct here. With respect to the Clang behaviour, the description of the signature indicates that the mangling should be unique. With respect to the GCC behaviour, the "does not declare" wording is meant to say that the friends declared by each specialization is unique.

Comment: Not sure I understand your point about msvc: According to [over#match.viable-3](https://eel.is/c++draft/over#match.viable-3), only one viable function should be there...

Comment: @Jarod42 But they are free functions and we dispatch ADL via `Base&`; without vtables overload resolution should not be able to know which derived specialization we are actually passing, right? Meaning overload resolution will arguably not have any information that can be used to match the requires-clauses (which itself is very weird, but also a quite contrived example).

Comment: Hmm, based on my previous comment, maybe MSVC is wrong to report an ambigious call, when actually no function should be found to be viable, as satisfaction of constrains shouldn't be checkable?

Comment: With "friend lookup" (as it is not exactly ADL), `foo(s1)` should only add in candidate set both `foo` from `S<1>` (then indeed , not sure if current wording allows constraint checking). but msvc has ambiguity with `foo` from `S<1>` and `S<2>`...

Comment: @Jarod42 It may be that this corner case is simply not well-specified in the standard. I'm still not sure whether both functions would be _candidates_ for the call, but I agree that at most one or even none, respectively, should be viable candidates, as constraints checking should fail other by a failed constraint or by the fact that the constraint lacks sufficient information for it to be checked, respectively. I updated the answer accordingly ("MSVC is probably also wrong ..."). Thanks for the feedback.