# Compiler variance for trailing requires-clauses on non-templated functions

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider the following example:

```
void f() requires true { }
int main() { f(); }
```

Clang<sup>(1)</sup> ([DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AYKPOmyj9fxpEdoI)) accepts this program, whereas GCC<sup>(1)</sup> ([DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PKOFAti0mDI3DGWw)) rejects it with the following error:

> ```
> error: constraints on a non-templated function
> ```

Note that the constraint expression can actually be used in Clang's case, as the following program is rejected by Clang:

```
void f() requires false { }
int main() { f(); }  //  // error: no matching function for call to 'f'
```

with Clang noting that that the declared `f` is not a candidate as the constraints were not satisfied (for it to be a candidate for the `f()` call; [DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nx5CcmK8LnfSEt7l)).

- Which compiler is correct here, and what is(/are) the relevant standard rule(/s) that govern this?

---

<sub>(1) GCC HEAD 11.0.0 20210124 and Clang HEAD 12.0.0 (20210124), `-std=c++20`.</sub>

Comment: I find them very interesting personally; I hope you keep posting these kinds of Q&As.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>*All standard references below refer, unless noted otherwise, to [N4861 (March 2020 post-Prague working draft/C++20 DIS)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/).*</sub>

---

This is a Clang bug, and GCC is correct to reject the program, as per [[dcl.decl]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.decl#4) (as well as [[temp.constr.decl]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.constr.decl#1)) [**emphasis** mine]:

> The optional *requires-clause* in an *init-declarator* or
> *member-declarator* **shall be present only if the declarator declares a templated function** ([dcl.fct]). When present after a declarator,
> the *requires-clause* is called the *trailing requires-clause*. [...]

The same paragraph also contains a (non-normative) example explicitly pointing out the OP's example as ill-formed:

> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> void f1(int a) requires true;       // error: non-templated function
>
> template<typename T>
> auto f2(T a) -> bool requires true; // OK
>
> // ...
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

We may note that in an earlier version of the (to become C++20) working draft, [N4810](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/n4810.pdf), [dcl.decl]/4 had a weaker requirement for where requires-clauses were allowed to appear:

> The optional *requires-clause* (Clause 13) in an *init-declarator* or *member-declarator* shall not be present when the declarator does not declare a function (9.2.3.5). [...]
>
> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> void f1(int a) requires true; // OK
>
> // ...
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

where the non-normative example of the use case of the OP was explicitly shown as well-formed. The original intent there was arguably to allow constraining of non-template member functions of class templates based on the template parameters of the class template:

```
#include <iostream>

template<bool B>
struct S {
    void f() requires   B  { std::cout << "true\n"; }
    void f() requires (!B) { std::cout << "false\n"; }
};

int main() { 
    S<true>{}.f();   // true
    S<false>{}.f();  // false
}
```

this is still allowed in the final state (intended for C++20) of [dcl.decl]/4 in N4861, where the restriction is to that of a *templated function* (see *templated entity* in [[temp.pre]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.pre#8), particularly [[temp.pre]/8.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.pre#8.3)), which does not only cover function templates (and function template members of non-templates and template class templates), but also non-template member functions of class templates.

---

Clang bug report:

- [Bug 48870 - Accepts-invalid for requires-clause on non-templated function](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48870)

Comment: Nice work showing how the text changed between versions, and the intent behind the original text and the changes.

Comment: Remarkable change. I recall relaxing the `typename` requirement for C++11, which now can be used on nested names outside templates as well.  There's no hard need for that, but it simplified the rule.

Comment: @MSalters Note that this change in restrictions applied only to a feature that did not exist prior to C++20, so that the changes were only applied to a working draft. Imo there are still some unclarities as to the rules for constrained non-template friend functions, though, and I highlighted some compiler variance in this regard (corner cases) [in the following Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64758699/overloading-of-hidden-friends-by-differences-only-in-mutually-exclusive-requir).

Comment: Implied template - `void foo(auto)->requires false;`